# Why would the following code run?

Tags: java, for-loop

Consider the following code:

```
int x = 0;   
for(System.out.println("Confuse!"); Math.random()>0.5; x--)
{
}
```

I am quite puzzled on how this code would compile (it actually prints "Confuse!"). What is the explanation behind this? Wasn't it the case that in a for loop we have for(initiation;condition;increment)? Shouldn't we define an int variable there? Or does that not really matter and the initiation can be anything?

Comment: [For loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: For what reason do think it *wouldn't* run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the 1<sup>st</sup> section in `for` loop is an *initialization section*, doesn't bound you to have only initialization expression there. You can have any valid expression there. For example, you can even give an increment expression there, like in below case:

```
int i = 0;
for (++i; i < 10; i++) {
}
```

The 1<sup>st</sup> section is only executed once. It can either initialize `i` to `0`. But that we have already done outside. Here we have just incremented `i` by `1`.

See [JLS §14.14.1 -  Basic `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) for more details on this:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement

ForStatementNoShortIf:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) StatementNoShortIf

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
    StatementExpressionList

StatementExpressionList:
    StatementExpression
    StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
```

As specified, the `ForInit` part can be a list of valid *expression*, **or** a *local variable declaration*. You can't have both. And method invocation is a valid expression, and hence it is completely valid syntax there. See [JLS §14.8 - Expression Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)

Here's a more confusing example denoting the expression list:

```
for (System.out.println("World"),System.out.println("Hello"); i < 10; i++) { }
```

Do you notice that the 2 print statements are separated by *comma*? And that is a valid `for` statement. It will print `"World"`, followed by `"Hello"`.

Now, you can try putting both *local variable declaration*, and a print statement there, or an increment statement, and you'll see it failing.

Comment: You might want to put a note that if you go with a local variable declaration, you can't chain any other type of expression. With an example :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Isn't that obvious with the syntax? Should I add that?

Comment: The syntax table is descriptive for you and me, but maybe not to user with -5 downvotes. I would. I'm upvoting you either way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, updated my answer. It's better to be explicit :)

Comment: That's great to know. Thank you very much for your answer. So we can as well have a for loop without any initializing declaration such as for(;i < 10: i++) {}, while having defined the variable i and assigned it a value previously?

Comment: @fogvajarash You can even have `for(;;)` :) and that would be an infinite loop.